For loop working with int but not with double
I am trying to make a simple program that finds the sum of 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n. However, I have stumbled upon an interesting issue: this for loop works with int but not with double.
double num, result = 1;
  
double main(){

    printf("Input a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    for (double i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        result += 1/i;
    }

    printf("Result: %f", result);    

    return 0;
}

After replacing every int and %d with double and %f, the loop gets skipped and I cannot figure out why. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

You need %lf to read a double. %f reads a float.

Never using floating point numbers as loop iterators, since they may not be able to exactly represent every number of the loop.

Is it even correct for main to ever return double? :o

Another small issue: your program computes 1 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...

How does that loop work using int? If you use int i in your loop, then 1/i would result to 0 for any i > 1 due to integer division.

@Gerhardh you would of course need 1/(double)i instead of 1/i

@Jabberwocky I know but given all the other errors I am not sure if the OP did that. They only mentioned replacing int with double (even in main return type)

@Jabberwocky Or 1.0/i of course. Or perhaps OP has an interesting definition of "works". :-)

Main should return an int not a double.
Main should almost always return an int. Often other programs may rely on the return value of main, expecting 0 for successful execution and any other integer for errors. As such, any other programs aren't prepared to handle any return type other than an int, it's common practice to use int and also written as an expectation in in the c standard. See: Why does main have to return an int? and Program Startup.
Scanf reading the double as a float
When reading a double using scanf you need to be using %lf rather than %f. %f is used for reading float's.
Library inclusions and loop correction
In the code your provided you didn't include the stdio library but I'm assuming it's done on your end. Your loop also starts at a value of 1, even though you initialize result at 1. This means that your function is starting the loop by doing 1/1 and adding it to 1, giving you a value of 2 before going on to do the other calculations. You can fix this by either starting the loop at 2, or initializing result at 0. In the example code below I just started the for loop at 2.
Working Code
The code below should work, but make sure you understand the changes before implementing it so you can avoid future errors.
#include <stdio.h>

double num, result = 1;

int main(){

    printf("Input a number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num);

    for (double i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        result += 1/i;
    }

    printf("Result: %lf", result);

    return 0;
}


It would be cleaner to initialize result to 0, and start the loop with 1.

In your answer, you wrote: "As such, any other programs aren't prepared to handle any return type other than an int" -- This statement implies that it is the "other programs" that are responsible for not being able to deal with a double return value. However, it is usually rather the operating system that is responsible for "other programs" never being able to get 64 bits of information (which would be commonly required for a double return value). For example, on Linux, the return value is usually restricted to 7 or 8 or 32 bits of information.

@Jabberwocky True, i just thought they might have had a reason for initializing it to 1.

@AndreasWenzel Good point
